# SQL Query using pivot and group by on SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, pivot-table, date-format

I have a punch clock database in SQL 2008 and would like to select the data to get the results using pivot and group by date (not time) and name. So for one Name, I want to have all PunchTime of a the same day in the same row.

```
ORIGINAL TABLE                  RESULT TABLE            
| NAME   | PUNCHTIME         |  | NAME   | TIME1             | TIME2             | TIME3             | TIME4             |
------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   John |2015-06-01 10:00:00|  |   John |2015-06-01 10:00:00|2015-06-01 12:00:00|2015-06-01 13:00:00|2015-06-01 21:00:00|
|   John |2015-05-30 21:34:27|  |   Amy  |2015-06-01 11:14:00|2015-06-01 17:00:00|                   |                   |
|   John |2015-06-01 10:00:00|  |   Amy  |2015-06-02 09:15:00|2015-06-02 12:25:00|                   |                   |
|    Amy |2015-06-01 11:14:00|  |   Amy  |2015-06-03 17:35:00|                   |                   |                   |
|   John |2015-06-01 12:00:00|  |   John |2015-05-30 09:04:27|2015-05-30 21:34:27|                   |                   |
|   John |2015-06-01 13:00:00|
|    Amy |2015-06-01 17:00:00|
|   John |2015-06-01 21:00:00|
|    Amy |2015-06-02 09:15:00|
|    Amy |2015-06-02 12:25:00|
|    Amy |2015-06-03 17:35:00|
```

Comment: This question is at risk for deletion. Please update the question with any attempts you have made towards solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @PunchCount        Int = 0
        ,@PivotColumns      Varchar(Max)
        ,@Sql               Varchar(Max)

Select   @PivotColumns = ''
        ,@Sql = ''

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#Punches') Is Not Null Drop Table #Punches;

Create Table #Punches
(
     RowId          Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,Name           Varchar(100)
    ,PunchTime      DateTime
)

Insert into #Punches(Name, PunchTime) Values
 ('John','2015-06-01 10:00:00')
,('John','2015-05-30 21:34:27')
,('John','2015-06-01 10:00:00')
,('Amy','2015-06-01 11:14:00')
,('John','2015-06-01 12:00:00')
,('John','2015-06-01 13:00:00')
,('Amy','2015-06-01 17:00:00')
,('John','2015-06-01 21:00:00')
,('Amy','2015-06-02 09:15:00')
,('Amy','2015-06-02 12:25:00')
,('Amy','2015-06-03 17:35:00')

Select  @PunchCount = Max(t.PunchCount)
From    (
            Select   t.Name
                    ,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, t.PunchTime)) As PunchDate
                    ,Count(t.PunchTime) As PunchCount
            From    #Punches As t
            Group By t.Name
                    ,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, t.PunchTime))
        ) As t

;With PC As
(
    Select  1 As PunchCount

    Union All

    Select  (PunchCount + 1)
    From    PC
    Where   PunchCount < @PunchCount
)

Select  @PivotColumns = @PivotColumns + (t.TimeCol + Cast(PC.PunchCount As varchar(10)) + ',')
From    PC
        Cross Join
        (
            Select  'Time' As TimeCol
        ) As t

Select  @Sql = 'Select  Name,' + Substring(@PivotColumns,0,Len(@PivotColumns)) +
' From  ( ' +
        ' Select     p.Name ' +
                    ' ,p.PunchTime ' +
                    ' ,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, p.PunchTime)) As PunchDate ' +
                    ' ,(''Time'' + Cast((Row_Number() Over (Partition By p.Name,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, p.PunchTime)) Order By p.Name,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, p.PunchTime)),p.PunchTime)) As Varchar(10))) ' +
                    '  As RowNum ' +
        ' From  #Punches As p ' +
        ' ) As s ' +
    ' Pivot ' +
    ' ( ' +
    '   Max(PunchTime) ' +
    '   For RowNum In (' + Substring(@PivotColumns,0,Len(@PivotColumns)) + ') ' +
    ' ) As p '

----Print (@Sql)
Exec (@Sql)

GO
```